# paperclip and polymorphic association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, polymorphic-associations

I have multiple models that need images associated with them so have setup a polymorphic association.

The only thing is at the moment if i create an image for a "Post" and want it to be "200x200", it means that if i have declared multiple styles in my image model then i am going to get multiple sizes of an image that i don't necessarily need.

Is there a way of declaring that the "Post" model should only save in one or maybe 2 styles only, even if there are say 5 dimensions declared.

Example below

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

attr_accessible :photo
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small_blog => "250x250#", :large_blog => "680x224#", :thumb => "95x95#", :portfolio_square => "300x300#", :portfolio_small => "220x220#", :portfolio_large => "680x680#" },
:storage => :s3,
:url  => ":s3_domain_url",
:s3_protocol => 'http',
:path => "/images/:id/:style.:extension",
:s3_credentials => {
 :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
 :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
 :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
}
 end


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :images, as: :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
attr_accessible :image_id, :images_attributes, :imageable_id, :imageable_attributes


end
```

How would i only save particular styles? not all of them... Has anyone done this before?

Thanks